# What did Obi-Wan do while as a Force Ghost?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force, obi-wan-kenobi

From the Battle of Yavin to the Battle of Endor, Obi-Wan spent about 4 years as a Force Ghost.

Throughout these 4 years, we only witnessed him (in the movies) speaking to Luke from thin air a couple times and appearing before him to speak a few more times. Did he do anything else outside those times?

After all, he appears able to go anywhere in the galaxy instantaneously, and do anything he'd like - being that he is more powerful than any Sith can imagine - so what did he do with so much freedom and "power"?

If there's any answer to this at all, I'm interested to know the different versions in both canon and Legends.

Comment: Ghost-writing for Lucas,  obviously.

Comment: He was haunting houses.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of any direct references.

However we can assume he was helping guide Luke. Only appearing to him when he has to.

This is a little tenuous but.

> If you choose to face Vader, you will do it alone. *I cannot interfere.*

Which could imply that he had been interfering up to then. This could explain things like Luke landing next to Yoda's house. Or even managing to blow up the death star with all of ten minutes Jedi training.

Answer (score -3):

I would say he
Most likely either stayed nuetral or influenced the desires of the force as part of the force by figuratively whispering into the ears of those who needed guidance.

Comment: Do you have sources?

Comment: That is simply what forces ghost do and are. They are part of the force able to manifest.

Comment: At 2.5k rep you should know better by now than to post such a short, speculative answer with no sources. -1